# How can i use access security for class fields in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following scenario.

I have 15 type of ROLES for security like `ROLE_1 , ROLE_2 ..... ROLE_15`

Now i have the complex matrix where each field of entity has 5 different permission for each role

LIKE

`view , delete, readonly, undelete, edit, update`

e,g for `ID` `ROLE_1` HAS `VIEW` PERMISSION

`ID` `ROLE_2` HAS `READ` PERMISSION

`ID` `ROLE_3` HAS `DELETE` PERMISSION

How can i do that in symfony

Answer (score 0):

Use JMS http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle. Here is how using annotation:

```
<?php
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;

class YourClassName extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_1, ROLE_ANOTHER")
     */
    public function viewAction() {
    }

    /**
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_2")
     */
    public function editAction() {
    }

    //....
}
```

Or use Access Control List for advanced use case: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html